# Retain view's pressed state inside listview after adapter updates

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a fragment with `ListView`, and assigned `CursorAdapter` with `CursorLoader`.
ListView's items have Buttons in them.

Sotimes backend updates occur very often, and every time it happens, Buttons inside ListView loose their `pressed` state, so its becoming hard for user to press a button.

So is it possible to fix this?